# Testing residuals from a cox model with time dependent covariates

Tags: r, residuals, cox-model, time-varying-covariate

I'm doing survival analysis with time dependent covariates, using the counting process style. I already have a set of models and I want to test de residuals.
I'm having trouble with the lack of information about this subject, **it makes sense to test Schoenfield residuals for time-dependent covariates**?
I'm using R.

Answer (score 3):

You can plot the martingale residuals for each subject. For me deviance residuals are more clear, both can be computed in R.

```
dev <- resid(fit,type = "deviance")
```

In particular, these plots will enable outlying observations to be identified.

However, diagnostic plots for covariates are not so useful because there are a number of tdc for any, and it is not clear what the residuals for the null model should be plotted against.